# How to unit-test rxjs5?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, rxjs, reactive-programming

I've read through this "marble-string" docs, but I juts don't get it.

What I want to test is basically a "protocol". I have a "thing" which is connected to an Observable and which emits data. In my backend code with Rx.NET and C# I have written a helper to test protocols so that my tests look like this:

```
verifier.Send(new AddMaterialPickCommand(commandId, orderId, materialId: Guid.NewGuid(), quantity: 1))
            .FailWhen<CommandFailedEvent>(e => e.CommandId == commandId)
            .ThenExpect<MaterialPickAddedEvent>(e => e.EntityId == orderId)
            .ThenSend(new DeleteOrderCommand(commandId, orderId))
            .FailWhen<CommandFailedEvent>(e => e.CommandId == commandId)
            .ThenExpect<OrderDeletedEvent>(e => e.EntityId == orderId)
            .ExecuteAndWait(Timeout);
```

In C# its very easy to connect observables to all things and its also very easy to wait. IMO it is a very readable test code.

With Rxjs5, I didn't find any possibility to wait or do anything similar. So atm I'm failing at just checking that a single thing emitted by my observable is the one expected:

```
sut.setValue("key1", "key2");
sut.getObservable("key1", "key2")
    .subscribe(value => {
       expect(value).toBe("testValue")  // I want either execute this or fail after a timeout
    });
```

setValue actually calls `next()` on a BehaviourSubject.

I'm clueless, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, one way is with a timeout as demonstrated in this example ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/squ1mwhn/13/)):

```
// Generates a value every second starting one second after subscription
const eventEmulatorStream = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);

// Listen to the event stream and timeout after 500 ms.
// On timeout an error will be generated that will be caught in the 
// 'error' part of the subscribe.
eventEmulatorStream
    .timeout(500)
    .subscribe({
        next: value => console.log(value),
        error: err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
    });
```

I suggest that you take a look at the RxJS [reference](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html), there are loots of goodies in there. Depending on how and where you are using RxJS you might need to import/load some things to get access to some of the features, but it should all be explained quite clearly in the RxJS documentation.